# Upload multiple images to firebase - blob crashing app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, blob

Can't seem to find a similar scenario to what I am experiencing.

I have a user run through a series of steps in my app taking photos along the way and saving them to the redux store. On the last screen they can upload the photos to firebase storage.

On this final (upload) screen I am pulling the photos from the store using "useSelector" and saving as a variable.

I run the photo through a function to turn into a blob which allows me to upload to firebase. Once I attempt to loop through or just run back to back functions converting each image to a blob my app crashes. Example - if I create a second function called "uploadImages2" and repeat the code (using the second image) then add to my onPress handler it will crash my app. However if I run my blob function only once and upload only one image it works just fine.

I am looking for help finding a solution where I can loop through or run individual functions iterating through each image and uploading it to firebase.

Ideally I will run a loop through an array of the photos as the user can choose to upload anywhere from 10(minimum) to 16 (maximum) photos. For now I have just included 2 photos which I was testing with.

My app is managed by expo and I am using firebase V9.

Thank you for any assistance!

```js
import React from 'react';

import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Button, Text, ScrollView, View, Image } from 'react-native';


import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/storage';

import { useState } from 'react';

const Firebase = () => {

const thePhoto1 = useSelector((state) => state.pickupPhotos.photo1)
const thePhoto2 = useSelector((state) => state.pickupPhotos.photo2)
const tripId = useSelector((state) => state.pickupInfo.tripNumber)


const firebaseConfig = {
//removed
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const storage = getStorage(); //the storage itself

const uploadImages = async () => {

const fileName = "/" + tripId.toString() + "/" + Math.random()
const ref2 = ref(storage, fileName); //how the image will be addressed inside the storage

        const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
        };
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', thePhoto1, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    })

    uploadBytes(ref2, blob); //upload images
    console.log("done")

  };

    return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

        <Image source={{uri: thePhoto1}} style={styles.theImg} />
        <Image source={{uri: thePhoto2}} style={styles.theImg} />

        <Button 
            style={styles.submitBtn}
            title='UPLOAD PHOTOS TO FIREBASE'
            onPress={ () => {
                uploadImages()
              }             
            }
        /> 
    </ScrollView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    theImg: {
        width:275,
        height:275,
        position:'relative',
        marginTop:10,
        left:10
    },
    submitBtn: {
        marginBottom:80
    }
});

export default Firebase;
```

Answer (score 0):

use uploadBytesResumable instead

```js
   import {getDownloadURL, getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable} from "firebase/storage";

   
   const uploadImage = async (uri: any, fileName: string) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(uri);
            const blobFile = await response.blob();
            const storageRef = ref(storage, 'gallery/' + fileName);

            const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blobFile);

            const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(snapshot?.ref);
            console.log('Download URL:', imageUrl);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading or retrieving image:', error);
        }
    };
```